# Finding Jquery tab group

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-tabs

I am working on a application with multiple nested level tabs in the UI. I am using jQuery for the tabs. I know we can find the selected tab knowing the tab group id like

```
$('#exampleTabs').tabs('option','selected');
```

But I need the reverse. That is I need to find the id of the tab group of the currently selected tab. Let me give an example tab structure below. Assume Tab 1, Tab 2, Tab 3, Tab 4 belong to 'Group1' and Tab 2.1, Tab 2.2, Tab 2.3 belong to 'Group2'(i.e `$('#Group1').tabs()` and `$('#Group2').tabs())`.

```
-Tab 1
-Tab 2
    +-Tab 2.1
    +-Tab 2.2 ---> assume we are here
    +-Tab 2.3
-Tab 3
-Tab 4
```

So, given we are at tab 'Tab 2.2', I have to get the id 'Group2'. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating things. There's nothing called tab group in jQuery UI. What you are referring to is merely the semantic setup of your tabs, which acts just like parent and children elements.

When you're looking at Tab 2.2, Tab 2 is the active tab in the parent tabs, so you will only have to check the selected option of the parent tabs to get what you call "tab group".

To get the selected tab you can do this:

```
var parentTab = currentTabs.closest('.ui-tabs').tabs('option', 'selected');
```

If you want the id of the parent tab panel it will be faster and easier to do this:

```
var parentTabId = currentTabs.closest('.ui-tabs-panel')[0].id;
```

Assuming `currenTabs` holds the children tab object (not the current tab).